# Perl parse JSON response as an array

Tags: json, angularjs, perl

I have a long sql query with a lot of derived columns and I'm trying to get it displayed in an angular page. I reached the point where I'm getting a json response back from the db but its returning each row as one big object instead of an array. I'm using perl to query the db and I've tried a bunch of ways to parse it and I haven't gotten it yet.

The subroutine:

```
require fileWithAllImports.pl #has CGI, JSON, etc
%response                 = {};
$response{error}{code}    = "0";
$response{error}{message} = "OK";

$sql = "select c.title as Content....";
$sql  = &database_escape_sql($sql); #I think its self-explanatory what this does
%hash = &database_select_as_hash_with_auto_key(
$sql,"content ... "); #more columns

foreach $i ( keys %hash ) {

        $id                              = $i;
        $response{$i}{content}           = $hash{$i}{content};
       ...
    } #again all of the columns

print_json_response(%response);
```

The angular call:

```
$http.get("/folder/ofSubroutine.cgi")
        .then(function(minutes_results) {
            console.log(minutes_results);
```

and the json repsonse:

```
{"6":{"derivedcolumn":"123","anotherderived":"987",..},"11":{"derived column":"123"}...}
```

I believe `ng-repeat` only works with an array so how would I parse the response from the server into an array?

Comment: looking at this backwards, sending array of objects from server is the norm

Comment: I'm confused? Most of the queries on the other pages seem to have no issue returning an array. Though I don't know if they deal with derived columns

Comment: Your issue is clearly with `database_select_as_hash_with_auto_key`. You're requesting a hash, massaging the data a little, and returning a hash. How could that possibly produce an array? Show us the code to the subroutine I mentioned, and perhaps we can suggest the changes you'll need to make.

Comment: Also, `%response = {}` is assigning a hash reference, which is a scalar, into a hash, which is a problem. You should `use strict` and `use warnings` to catch things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the back end, you could place the data into a separate array instead of adding each row to the hash:

```
foreach $i ( keys %hash ) {
    push @{$response{data}}, { id => $i,
                               content => $hash{$i}{content},
                               ... ,
                             };
}
print_json_response( %response );
```

Or on the front end, convert your associative array to a regular array:

```
$http.get("/folder/ofSubroutine.cgi")
    .then(function(minutes_results) {
        console.log(minutes_results);
        var minutes_results_as_array = [];
        for (var key in minutes_results) {
            if (key != "error") {
                minutes_results[key].id = key;
                minutes_results_as_array.push(minutes_results[key]);
            }
        }
        // display minutes_results_as_array as you see fit
      } );
```